# Integration of TFS and Mantis

Tags: tfs, bug-tracking, issue-tracking, mantis

In our company there exist in different teams two different systems to manage the issues: Mantis and TFS. Now we have a project where a team must handle changes in both systems.

Is there a programm or a tool where tickets of TFS and Mantis can be viewed. At best there is the posibility to define relations between the tickets and prioritize them independently of the system the tickets come from.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see there is any exist tool to integrate TFS and Mantis. But there is a source control integration plugin framework for MantisBT, which supports for Github, Gitlab, Bitbucket, Gitweb, Cgit, Subversion, Mercurial, etc. You could refer to the plugin and implement TFS integration:

https://github.com/mantisbt-plugins/source-integration

Or you can use [Mantis Bug Tracker REST API](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/29959/mantis-bug-tracker-rest-api/7Lt6zkP) and [TFS REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/?view=vsts-rest-4.1) to program your own tool.